# jquery a good method to handly last output to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a good way to handle a link click of different lines
Each line is added at different times and i want only the most recently added line's links to be clickable. they are all under the same div tag

```
ex:
line 1:  "this is a line <link here>"  <-- dont want these to be clickable
line 2:  "this is a line <link here>"  <-- but still viewed
line 3:  "this is a line <link here>"  <-- most recent line clickable
```

hopefully this is being explained correctly
the lines are added with .before function

So i added

to indicate each line. the link are indicated by a class id called talk_action and each line can contain more than one link. so somehow i need to set up an on click for the .talk_action which is clicked under the last paragraph. when the link is clicked it grabs the link id and passes it to a php file

```
ex:
<p>would you like to <a class='talk_action' id='shop'>shop</a> or talk about <a class='talk_action' id='quest'>quests</a></p>
```

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all the lines are in a `div` with `id="lines"`

```
$("#lines").on("click","a:last",function(){
     // your action here
});
```

This uses:

- [Event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) to always remain "updated" to the last link
- The [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to always match the last one
- The [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event

#### [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5baLd/)

Comment: @user2376313 Suggestion only.....if you are appending the links dynamically then you need to bind click event to a parent(existing) element.

Comment: No, still working on it. My links are dynamic and each line can contain more than one link.

Answer (score 2):

The ':last' selector may suitable for you

```
$( "a:last" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code will work as expected..
http://jsbin.com/afUKiJi/1/edit

```
$(".clickable").find('a').last().on('click',function(){
alert('last');
})
```

Comment: This will not stay updated if new lines are added and you'd have to remove the handlers each time a new element is added.

Comment: the above lines should be enclosed within a function and once new lines are added this func should be called and then would help the user's cause..just a thought by my side..

Comment: How would that prevent the actions on elements who used to be last from being called?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g2yW/4/). This will also take into account recently added anchors and is using event delegation in jquery.

```
$('div').on('click','a:last', function(){
console.log(this);
});
```